# Zohar Commentary Recommendations

Tags: zohar

After this rosh Hashanah I realized I'm at a point where I'm able to study the Kabbalah. Rabbi Moses Cordovero in Or Neerav puts the age at which one should begin at twenty and right now is nearing the end of my twentieth year.

I'm looking for the most rigorous commentary on the Zohar. I can approximately understand the Aramaic but my understanding is not totally fluid. I'm familiar with the existence of the sulam commentary which I've seen in many places (although I've never opened it up) but I just don't know if it's the best one. I'm a bit skeptical of *sulam* because various popular Kabbalah organizations spun off from his teachings are of a questionable nature; with matters as important as the Kabbalah I need to be sure the commentary I'm appealing to is absolutely pristine.

The other possibility is *matok midvash*.
My issue is that there are many different schools of Kabbalah and so whichever commentary I'm looking at I'd want to know what school it is coming from.

Ultimately I'm going to ask an authority but I also would like to do my own research so I can be informed. Any ideas would help. Thanks

Comment: Hi @theideasmith just to let you know that there are authorities that say Kabbalah should only really start from age 40. Refer to the Shach here - https://www.sefaria.org/Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.246.6.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Thank you for prudently mentioning those other opinions.

Comment: Also try seeking a true master to learn from (ie קבלה)

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/The_Beginning_of_Wisdom.1.1

Comment: Shach was younge then 40 when he learnt Kabbalah

Comment: Mosok Mdvash is ur best bet that's what I use . It's awesome

Comment: He also wrote shach at 24

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel is that crazy to write a Perush/sefer at the age of 24?